# 403 Forbidden When Using AuthzSVNAccessFile

Tags: svn

I've had a nicely functioning svn server running on windows that uses Apache for access.  In the original setup every user had access to all repositories, but I recently needed the ability to grant a user only access to one repository.  I uncommented the AuthzSVNAccessFile line in my httpd.conf file and pointed it to an accessfile and setup the access file, but I get a 403 Forbidden when I go to mydomain.com/svn .  If I recomment out this line then things work again. I also made sure I uncommented the LoadModule authz_svn_module and verified that it was point to the correct file.

Below is the Location section of my httpd.conf and my svnaccessfile

```
httpd.conf (location section only)

<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath C:\svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repositories"
    AuthUserFile passwd
    Require valid-user
    AuthzSVNAccessFile svnaccessfile
</Location>
```

(I want a more complex policy in the long run but just did this to test the file out)
svnaccessfile

```
[svn:/]
* = rw
```

I have also tried just the below for the svnaccessfile.

```
[/]
* = rw
```

I also restart the service after each change just to make sure it is taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I have resolved the issue by changing the start of the Location tag to

The difference being the trailing /

Answer (score 1):

What got filtered out of the above answer was the <Location /svn/>

You also need the:

[/]

section in your acl file with the appropriate permissions

Answer (score 1):

This only works if you want to allow everyone access.

My ACL file is simply:

```
[/]
scott = rw
```

This produces a 403 error, but if I change the ACL file so it instead is:

```
[/]
* = rw
```

...that allows access.

Still working on figuring out why * allows access but a specific user causes the 403 error (I have that user defined in an htpasswd file that is referenced with AuthUserFile)